# In App Purchase - No purchase to restore

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to figure out if I get a message back when a **user tries to restore an In App Purchase but there was no purchase ever made.**

Right now, as soon as a user taps the `restoreButton`, I disable the `restoreButton`.

```
- (IBAction)purchaseRestore:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"4 IBAction Purchase Restore Method: start");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
    NSLog(@"4 Purchase Restore: SKPayment Queue two lines... log in user");
    restoreButton.enabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"4 Restore button enabled: No");
}
```

So if they click the `restoreButton`, and have nothing to restore then the `restoreButton` just stays grayed out.

**I would like to do something like a `UIAlert` or change the `restoreButton` text if that happens to say "You don't have any items to Restore", but I assume I need to get some message back from Apple saying "no items to restore" so I can fire off that code.**

Here's my `updatedTransactions` code if needed:

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"5 Finish Transaction");

                restoreButton.hidden = YES;
                NSLog(@"5 restore button hidden: Yes");

                [self showButtonThree];
                NSLog(@"5 Show Button Three");

                NSLog(@"5 Restored: End");

                break;
```

**Any ideas?  Thanks!**

Update

Tried this:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    NSLog(@"Completed Transactions Finished");
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              @"Restored succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

But that was popping up whether there was a transaction to restore or not.  I had assumed this would get called if there was no transaction to restore maybe, but makes sense that it wouldn't:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Completed Transactions Failed with Error");
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              @"Not restored succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official Apple documentation for [restoreCompletedTransactions](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions)

> After the transactions are delivered, the payment queue calls the
>   observer’s `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` method.
>   If an error occurred while restoring transactions, the observer will
>   be notified through its
>   `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` method.

Comment: Thanks!  Pointed me in the right direction.  So from what I've tried, its looking like `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` gets called no matter if theres a purchase to restore or not huh?

Comment: So that would be a method to not use a `UIAlert` in, but moreso to remove the `restoreButton`?

Comment: You can keep a count or flag someone to tell you whether you got a restored transaction between the call to `restoreCompletedTransactions` and the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` invocation.